# How to know the destination address of a multisig?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, multi-signature, bitcoin-cli

Run this command:

`bitcoin-cli getrawtransaction 56214420a7c4dcc4832944298d169a75e93acf9721f00656b2ee0e4d194f9970 2`

You will see the first vout is a multisig as follow:

```
 {
      "value": 0.04030000,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "2 02c08786d63f78bd0a6777ffe9c978cf5899756cfc32bfad09a89e211aeb926242 033e81519ecf373ea3a5c7e1c051b71a898fb3438c9550e274d980f147eb4d069d 036d568125a969dc78b963b494fa7ed5f20ee9c2f2fc2c57f86c5df63089f2ed3a 3 OP_CHECKMULTISIG",
        "hex": "522102c08786d63f78bd0a6777ffe9c978cf5899756cfc32bfad09a89e211aeb92624221033e81519ecf373ea3a5c7e1c051b71a898fb3438c9550e274d980f147eb4d069d21036d568125a969dc78b963b494fa7ed5f20ee9c2f2fc2c57f86c5df63089f2ed3a53ae",
        "reqSigs": 2,
        "type": "multisig",
        "addresses": [
          "1PfTD843HiN2PPpxFnMwyxN7se6MEf2ech",
          "1JXc8zsSeAPwqfAzLbBnZxNTfetZexH2bW",
          "1Ng4YU2e2H3E86syX2qrsmD9opBHZ42vCF"
        ]
      }
 },
```

And from [bitinfochart](https://bitinfocharts.com/bitcoin/tx/56214420a7c4dcc4832944298d169a75e93acf9721f00656b2ee0e4d194f9970#perv=5LB2z&next=&), we can see the destination address is not

1. `1PfTD843HiN2PPpxFnMwyxN7se6MEf2ech`
2. `1JXc8zsSeAPwqfAzLbBnZxNTfetZexH2bW`
3. `1Ng4YU2e2H3E86syX2qrsmD9opBHZ42vCF`

but `3844dWM7n5c1oAYhtQc5uLtKB6TjN5PSW4`

Can someone tell me how to get the destination address, `3844dWM7n5c1oAYhtQc5uLtKB6TjN5PSW4`?

Comment: You keep overwriting my edits but you seem to misunderstand their purpose. See my answer, `3844dWM7n5c1oAYhtQc5uLtKB6TjN5PSW4` **is not** the "destination address": their is no concept of address for the bare multisig `scriptPubKey`s. The explorer you consulted misleaded you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website displays the `scriptPubKey` of the first output as if it was a P2SH (more commonly used for multisig), but it's not.

This is a bare multisig. As another explorer example, [Esplora displays it more accurately](https://blockstream.info/tx/56214420a7c4dcc4832944298d169a75e93acf9721f00656b2ee0e4d194f9970?expand) (there is no address for this Script type).

The `addresses` field of `getrawtransaction` (and a few other commands) output will for bare multisig outputs give you the P2PKH address of each of the key used in the multisig.

Comment: What do you mean the scriptPubKey of the first output? There are many fields in scriptPubKey.

Comment: So those who own these three addresses can spend the bitcoin?

Comment: *1st question:* I mean the actual `scriptPubkey` (or output locking script), not the JSON entry of the `getrawtransaction` output.
*2nd question:* In this specific case (2 of 3), 2 of them agreeing can.

Comment: Last question. Where can I find the actual `scriptPubkey `? Thank you.

Comment: The actual scriptPubkey is represented as hexadecimal in the `["scriptPubkey"]["hex"]` JSON entry.